# Telegram Bot does not have Chat_Id or Message_Id?

Tags: telegram-bot

I am trying to create two bots which will talk to each other. For that I need to know Telegram Bot ChatId or MessageId? How may I suppose to get it to reply the chat and deleting the chats.

[image: Response Of My Bot Rose]

Answer (score 0):

As per the official FAQ, bots can't talk to each other: https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesnt-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots